# Which function satisfies these constraints?

Tags: exponential-function

What is the simplest monotone increasing, continuous function that satisfies these constraints?

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)} &= e^x \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} &= 1
\end{align}

I guess this implies that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{f(x)}{-xe^{x}} &= 1?
\end{align}

Comment: Hm, define "simplest" please.

Comment: @SimpleArt I only added that adjective because I realize that there are infinitely many such functions, and I don't actually need all of them.  I just want a "simple function" in the sense that I can evaluate it efficiently in a computer program.

Comment: Repeated applications of L'Hospital's rule yields $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{-(x+n)e^x}=1$$which may be of use.

Comment: $$\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}=e^x$$

$$\implies\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}\right)^a=\left(e^x\right)^a=e^{ax}=\frac{f(ax)}{f(-ax)}$$

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}\right)^a=\frac{f(ax)}{f(-ax)}$$

Comment: $x + 1$ for $x > 0$, $(1 - x) / e^{-x}$ for $x < 0$ is pretty simple.

Comment: @T.Bongers That was fast!  Could you please add an answer.  If you had a method for discovering this, I'm also interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of functions work, e.g.

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} x + 1 & x \ge 0 \\ e^x ({1 - x}) & x < 0\end{array}\right.$$

---

I came up with this in two steps:

- Hoped that $f(x) = x$ for positive $x$ works. It doesn't, because it's zero at zero.
- Fix this by adding $1$, or any positive number to it.

Comment: (Promoting my comment to an answer at the request of the asker)

Comment: I like these two steps.  +1

Answer (score 8):

Differentiating $f(-x) = f(x) \exp(-x)$, we have $-f'(-x) = (f'(x) - f(x)) \exp(-x)$.  If $f$ is to be monotone increasing we'll need this to be nonpositive, so $f'(x) - f(x) \le 0$.  You could take

$$ f(x) = \cases{1 + x & for $x \ge 0$\cr
                 (1-x) \exp(x) & for $x < 0$\cr}$$

EDIT:  But there is an analytic solution, namely

$$ f(x) = \frac{x e^x}{e^x-1} $$

Comment: Another question would be to prove that no such function can be analytic.

Comment: @MarkFischler ... but not a correct question.

Comment: I just realized that my fixed answer is now the same as your analytic answer.

Answer (score 4):

The odd part of $\log(f(x))$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\vphantom{\frac12}\log(f(x))-\log(f(-x))\right)
&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}\right)\\
&=\frac x2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $f(x)=e^{\frac x2+g(x)}$ where $g(x)$ is an even function.

We also want $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac x2+g(x)-\log(x)\right)=0$. Thus, let $g(x)=\log\left(\frac{x/2}{\sinh(x/2)}\right)$ and get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\frac{x/2\,e^{x/2}}{\sinh(x/2)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac x2\left(1+\coth\left(\frac x2\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not monotone increasing?

Comment: I fixed $g(x)$. It should now be monotonic.

Comment: this is very interesting

Comment: @NeilG: as I commented on Robert Israel's answer, this turns out to be the same as his analytic answer.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to evaluate this in a numerically stable way.  How would I do it if I have access to standard math functions (like log1p expm1 logaddex)?  The problem is that $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is not stable around zero.

Comment: @NeilG: $\frac{x\,e^x}{\operatorname{expm1}(x)}$ may work better.

Comment: You're right, I think that's best.  scipy does that for their exprel function with a special case that for small x, the ratio is roughly 1.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=e^{x}(-x+1)$ when $x<0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ when $x\geq 0$.